# How can I be an interpreter?

Tags: multiple-languages, translation

I'm Bangladeshi and my native language is Bangla/Bengali. If I can speak English fluently, can I be an interpreter?

And is there any course for interpretation?

Comment: Welcome to LL.SE! Are you interested in being an interpreter in a particular country, like Bangladesh? The answer probably varies by country.

Comment: Did you tried google search? I tried "become interpreter" and Google search completion suggest many relevant questions other people asked (and answers). Training/certification IS dependent by the country, as Tommi correctly suggested. To be interpreter, English is not enough: you need to be able to sell yourself (your skills), find your customers. Google can certainly find you many courses for interpretation - but it is YOUR OWN responsibility to find out which ones are good, because 80% of the are not, just as a general law of the universe (80% of anything is irrelevant crap).

Answer (score 1):

That depends on a few variables. If you want to be a legal or medical interpreter, you are more likely to have clients who don't speak English. However, if the majority of medical and legal professionals in Bangladesh are already fluent in English as they are presumably in India, they will have no need for your help. If you wish to be a corporate or tourist interpreter, it will depend on whether or not the majority of Bangladeshi business executives and others who can afford to travel can already speak English. If you can interpret to or from a third language, you will have even more opportunities.

Especially if you live outside of Bangladesh, it might be difficult to make a living full-time as an interpreter, but I am sure you can find work on an on-call basis. Again, this assumes that there is a significant population of Bangladeshi ex-pats who never learned English. As for interpretation courses, many universities have offerings.

Answer (score 0):

If you speak English fluently (and live in Bangladesh), you can get a job where you use your English skills as a **part** of services you provide: tourist guide, import/export trade, whatever. So you are not making living by full-time interpreting, but you still use your English to make living.